# Can't deploy functions with Crashlytics triggers

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, crashlytics

I write many functions that trigger by Firebase features and I can deploy them but only functions that trigger by Crashlytics I can't deploy.

```
exports.sendOnVelocityAlert = functions.crashlytics.issue().onVelocityAlert(event => {
    const data = event.data;

    const issueId = data.issueId;
    const issueTitle = data.issueTitle;
    const appName = data.appInfo.appName;
    const appPlatform = data.appInfo.appPlatform;
    const latestAppVersion = data.appInfo.latestAppVersion;
    const crashPercentage = data.velocityAlert.crashPercentage;
    const slackMessage = `<!here|here> There is an issue ${issueTitle} (${issueId}) ` + `in ${appName}, version ${latestAppVersion} on ${appPlatform} that is causing ` + `${parseFloat(crashPercentage).toFixed(2)}% of all sessions to crash.`;

    return notifySlack(slackMessage)/then(() => {
      console.log(`Posted velocity alert ${issueId} successfully to Slack`);
    });
});
```

I always see this error "Cannot read property 'issue' of undefinded" when I deploy.

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'issue' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/y8/tbbq9y5j12jc5rlwcmt5smgm0000gn/T/fbfn_10408f4KU3uXJsLQc/index.js:261:53)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:18:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:32:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I use Firebase CLI v3.16.0, node v8.9.3, npm v5.5.1 and version of dependencies in package.json are below.

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.5.1",
    "child-process-promise": "^2.2.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.5",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "mkdirp-promise": "^5.0.1",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Any ideas to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase CLI runs the code you have locally to parse your triggers. Though your `package.json` has a completely valid dependency, it looks like the version of `firebase-functions` you have installed is from before `firebase.crashlytics` was a introduced in October.

Could you try running `npm install` from your `functions` directory and see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: It was fixed by 
`npm install firebase-functions@latest --save`
`npm install -g firebase-tools`
You save my day.
 Thank You.